# ffmpeg add picture to audio without reduction in quality

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, compression, video-conversion

I am trying to combine a picture and an audio file without any quality loss. I am currently using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -r 1 -loop 1 -i ./pic.JPG -i ./audio.wav -acodec copy -r 1 -shortest howitgoes.avi
```

This works well for keeping the audio bit rate the same but the picture (which is 4000x6000) is noticeably compressed.

Does anyone know of a better ffmpeg command or any way of combining a picture with an audio file without loss of quality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 1 -loop 1 -i pic.JPG -i audio.wav -c copy -shortest howitgoes.avi
```

This will [stream copy](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-copy) the JPG instead of re-encoding it. Think of it like a copy and paste. No re-encoding, no lossy encoder involved, no [generation loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generation_loss), and your requirement of no quality loss is achieved.

Most players won't like 1 fps, so if that is the case change `-framerate 1` to `-framerate 10`, or add the `-r 10` output option.

Comment: This answer solves the problem I stated by copying the inputs directly together. I think it is worth mentioning that part of the issue I had was that I was comparing the video image in VLC media player with the default photo viewer and they are rendering the image differently. When I run the video in quicktime it is the same as the default photo viewer.